# Finding indexes of strings in a string array in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I have two string arrays and I want to find where each string from the first array is in the second array, so i tried this:

```
for i  = 1:length(array1);
    cmp(i) = strfind(array2,array1(i,:));
end
```

This doesn't seem to work and I get an error: "must be one row".

Comment: Do the two arrays have the same strings, but at different locations?

Comment: strfind is used to find a string within another string, not within an arrays of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, an array of strings is nothing but a char matrix. This can be quite restrictive because all of your strings must have the same number of elements. And that's what @neerad29 solution is all about.

However, instead of an array of strings you might want to consider a cell array of strings, in which every string can be arbitrarily long.  I will report the very same @neerad29 solution, but with cell arrays. The code will also look a little bit smarter:

```
a = {'abcd'; 'efgh'; 'ijkl'};
b = {'efgh'; 'abcd'; 'ijkl'};

pos=[];
for i=1:size(a,1)
    AreStringFound=cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x,a(i,:)),b);
    pos=[pos find(AreStringFound)];
end
```

But some additional words might be needed:

- `pos` will contain the indices, `2 1 3` in our case, just like @neerad29 's solution
- `cellfun()` is a function which applies a given function, the `strcmp()` in our case, to every cell of a given cell array. `x` will be the generic cell from array `b` which will be compared with `a(i,:)`
- the `cellfun()` returns a boolean array (`AreStringFound`) with `true` in position `j` if `a(i,:)` is found in the j-th cell of `b` and the `find()` will indeed return the value of `j`, our proper index. This code is more robust and works also if a given string is found in more than one position in `b`.

Answer (score 0):

`strfind` won't work, because it is used to find a string within another string, not within an array of strings. So, how about this:

```
a = ['abcd'; 'efgh'; 'ijkl'];
b = ['efgh'; 'abcd'; 'ijkl'];

cmp = zeros(1, size(a, 1));

for i = 1:size(a, 1)
    for j = 1:size(b, 1)
        if strcmp(a(i, :), b(j, :))
            cmp(i) = j;
            break;
        end
    end
end

cmp =

     2     1     3
```